# SQL CLR no longer deploys to SQL 2008

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio-2010, clrstoredprocedure

I have a SQL CLR project that deploys stored procs to a server. For 2 years I've always been able to just right click the project and deploy. Yesterday I have started to get errors when I try to do that. I was able to deploy a new version last week but not this week.

```
 ------ Build started: Project: '', Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  '' -> E:\Development\Code\SqlDeployables\''\bin\Debug\''.dll
------ Deploy started: Project: '', Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Error: Class not registered.
Looking for object with CLSID: {475E0C1F-1E61-4197-9324-10A148C512F8}.
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've been searching around and can't find anything on the error. There has been no updates on the sql server since I could last deploy. I have uninstalled my VS2010 updates as well as .net updates on my machine and that has not done anything. The only updates I have not uninstalled were office ones, which I would think are not the problem.

Any ideas? I've tried resetting permissions on the sql machine. Removed Stored procs manually and redeploy. I've gone back to a previous version of the project and tried to deploy. Restarted SQL Server services on machine.

Visual Studio 2010
SQL Server 2008

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your visual studio install has gotten messed up. That CLSID points to the class `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Schema.Package.Sql.Internal.ManagedBuildLoggerComClass` in the com object `C:\Windows\system32\mscoree.dll`.

I would recommend trying to do a repair install on visual studio and see if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I couldn't figure out how to solve it. I think it might have something to do w/ a side-by-side install of VS2012, but I am not sure.

As a workaround I wrote my own T-SQL deploy script. The project builds all right, and it outputs dlls all right. All that is missing is the database deploy (ie, the commands that VS runs against the database to actually deploy your types and methods to the server). In the project's bin folder you may find the .sql file that VS generates; you can use this as a template. The deploy script will end up looking something like this:

```
USE SomeDatabase
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.[SomeFunction]') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.[SomeFunction]
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies WHERE NAME = 'SomeAssembly') DROP ASSEMBLY [SomeAssembly]
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [SomeAssembly] AUTHORIZATION dbo
FROM '\path\to\your\dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SomeFunction] ....
EXTERNAL NAME [SomeAssembly].[SomeAssembly.UserDefinedFunctions].[SomeMethod]
GO
```

Then deploy your stuff manually via SSMS.